# Error messages with Spring MVC 3.1 and ajax calls

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, bean-validation

I am working on a Spring MVC 3.1 web application, and almost all of my form submits are done using jQuery ajax calls and form serialization. This works great. I needed a way to pull the validation error messages back from the server, so I looked for an example. I found one online that essentially placed the BindingResult object into a custom JsonResponse object then returned it as the `@ResponseBody`. This also is working great! Here is where we get to my problem, though the `BindingResult` object comes back, none of the messages are being interpolated as they would if I was using the Spring:form tags. I looked into the issue, and found that I could attempt to overwrite the `SpringMessageSourceInterpolater` with a custom one, this helped, but now only the JSR-303 validation errors interpolate, not the actual `TypeMismatch` errors from the Spring binding. Here is an example of what I am doing:

```
     public @ResponseBody
     JSonResponse addQuote(@ModelAttribute("quote") @Valid QuoteBean quote, BindingResult result, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException
     {
        jsonResponse = new JsonResponse();

        //Some handle code

        jsonResponse.setStatus(JsonResponse.ResponseStatus.INVALID);
        jsonResponse.setResult(result.getAllErrors());

        return jsonResponse;
     }
```

As I said, the Json is serialized perfectly, and for the JSR-303 errors, the `defaultMessage` field of the error object is an interpolated message, but if the error is a Spring `TypeMismatch` (Like putting `1` into a field I'm binding to a Date), I instead end up with a long Spring generated message. I have tried adding message codes that correspond to all of the `error.getCodes()` that are on the object to no avail (such as `TypeMismatch.fieldname`). Surely someone has used Spring and Ajax and had this validation working, but I cannot find the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going through a similar issue, i.e. posting a form using jQuery. Currently I'm just returning the bindingresult as a string from the controller, using:

```
return bindingResult.getAllErrors()
```

As a temporary solution whilst developing the app, I'm parsing the returned json data and simply showing the defaultMessage(s) in an alert popup.

Have you managed to somehow assoicate the returned json defaultmessage(s) with the associated form input elements?

Would be really keen to hear of how you've handled this (in detail) as there isn't really much in terms of documentation about this, either from spring or otherwise.

Comment: What I ended up doing in order to get the messages next to the fields was similar to the Spring `form` tags, I add new `div`s next to all the fields, gave them a CSS class of `error` then added a custom attribute like `data-field='username'`. Then my Ajax callback scans the form looking for `div.error` with `$(this).data(response.field)` since the Spring `bindingResult` objects have a field name on them. Again, my problem is making those `defaultMessage` fields more friendly.

Comment: Hi Mark,

Thanks for the heads up, i had something in mind like this but being new to alot of technologies on this project (spring mvc / jquery etc) i have a really steep learning curve. Would you mind sharing your code - ie the form/divs and the ajax callback function ? This would really help.

Comment: Mark - i'm about to code this - your example would save me a lot of pain if you can help?